# Using OSMNX to retrieve nearby points of interest

Tags: python, openstreetmap, osmnx

hoping someone can help me?

In summary, I am trying to retrieve nearby points of interest based on a set of given coordinates.

After doing some research, I found a neat function

```
osmnx.pois.pois_from_point(point, distance=None, amenities=None, custom_settings=None)
```

That works for pubs, restaurants etc.

However, hotels are not classified amenities, and nor are any other tourism related places.

I found that those are identified with tourism:hotel key/value pair.

Does anyone have an idea of how to retrieve those? I didn't seem to find a function which accepts tourism as a parameter to pass in, nor I could find any way to pass in customer attribute values for filtering.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This part of the osmnx API is just broken :( Not all POIs are categorized as amenities in OSM. I have no experience with osmnx but maybe you can use `osmnx.core.osm_net_download()` instead with `infrastructure='node["tourism"="hotel"]'`?

Comment: The OSMnx points of interest (pois) module was originally designed to query OSM amenities and produce a geopandas GeoDataFrame. It is being generalized to query for all points of interest, amenity or otherwise, in https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx/pull/342 Comments/contributions are welcome there while it's in development.

Answer (score 4):

The OSMnx `features` module's functions take a flexible `tags` argument to query for any points of interest (or any OSM geospatial feature). See [the documentation](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-reference.html#module-osmnx.features). This code snippet retrieves restaurants, pubs, and hotels around downtown LA:

```py
import osmnx as ox
ox.settings.log_console = True

tags = {'amenity': ['restaurant', 'pub', 'hotel'],
        'building': 'hotel',
        'tourism': 'hotel'}
gdf = ox.features.features_from_point(point=(34.0483, -118.2531), dist=500, tags=tags)
gdf.shape #(109, 59)
```

Comment: `osmnx.pois.pois_from_point()` has become obsolete. POI can be retrieved using `osmnx.geometries.geometries_from_point()`, see https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#module-osmnx.pois